# Accessing variable values from a function nested within a function running a mysqli_fetch_assoc() function

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to generate a form, which amounts to a delete button under a table that presents client profile information on a site admin page. The table appears fine. The form, however, that I want to generate using a function within the while loop upon each one of its iterations does not include the variables $id, $firstname, $lastname, despite not generating an error message about undefined variables (my error message configuration is set to do this and does in fact work). I simply get a button that says Delete, and the form processing function fails because the $_POST values are null (as are the variable values in the form itself). The problem, therefore, must be with the form function's access to the table's variables.

If I include the form within the loop as an echo statement rather than as a function, the button works as desired. However, I would like to keep these two aspects separated for (I suppose) neurotic  and  idiosyncratic organizational preferences. I have previously had this type of issue, which I resolved by better understanding variable scope. But, the variable within the form function is defined as global, which leaves me at a loss.

Is this a peculiarity of the while loop and its interaction with the mysqli_fetch_assoc()?

I sought some indication of what might cause this at the php.net manual's description of mysqli_fetch_assoc(), but I could find nothing to suggest that this isn't allowed.

Any help would be grand. Also, as a self-taught fellow, please try and be constructive in you comments and criticisms. I am sure I have a very great deal to learn, and would be very grateful for guidance from those who know more than I.

Here is my table generating function:

```
function table_delete_client() {
$client_set = find_all_clients();   

while($client = mysqli_fetch_assoc($client_set)) {
    $id =           htmlentities($client['id']);
$firstname =        htmlentities($client['firstname']);
$lastname =         htmlentities($client['lastname']);
$position_en =      htmlentities($client['position_en']);
$position_fr =      htmlentities($client['position_fr']);
$division_en =      htmlentities($client['division_en']);
$division_fr =      htmlentities($client['division_fr']);
$organisation_en =  htmlentities($client['organisation_en']);       
$organisation_fr =  htmlentities($client['organisation_fr']);       
$telephone =        htmlentities($client['telephone']);
$email =        htmlentities($client['email']);
$email_list =       htmlentities($client['email_list']);        
$username =     htmlentities($client['username']);

echo "<table>" .
     "<tr>" .
         "<th>ID</th>" .
         "<td>$id</td>" .
     "</tr>" .
     "<tr>" .
             "<th>First Name</th>" .
     "<td>$firstname</td>" .
     "</tr>" .
     "<tr>" .
      "<th>Last Name</th>" .
      "<td>$lastname</td>" .
     "</tr>" .
     "<tr>" .
      "<th rowspan='2'>Position</th>" .
      "<td>$position_en</td>" .
     "</tr>" .
     "<tr>" .
      "<td>$position_fr</td>" .
     "</tr>" .
     "<tr>" .
      "<th rowspan='2'>Division</th>" .
      "<td>$division_en</td>" .
     "</tr>" .
     "<tr>" .
      "<td>$division_fr</td>" .
     "</tr>" .
         "<tr>" .
      "<th rowspan='2'>Organisation</th>" .
      "<td>$organisation_en</td>" .
     "</tr>" .
     "<tr>" .
      "<td>$organisation_fr</td>" .
     "</tr>" .
     "<tr>" .
      "<th>Telephone</th>" .
      "<td>$telephone</td>" .
     "</tr>" .
     "<tr>" .
      "<th>Email</th>" .
      "<td>$email</td>" .
     "</tr>" .
         "<tr>" .
      "<th>Email List</th>" .
      "<td>$email_list</td>" .
     "</tr>" .
     "<tr>" .
      "<th>Username</th>" .
      "<td>$username</td>" .
     "</tr>" .
         "</table>" .
     "<br />";

         form_delete_client();
        }
        mysqli_free_result($client_set);
}
```

Here is my form generating function nested within the 'while' loop:

```
function form_delete_client() { 
global $id;
global $firstname;
global $lastname;

echo $firstname;

echo "<form id=\"delete_client\" method=\"post\" action=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?sub_page=2\">" .
 "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"" . $id . "\" />" .
 "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"firstname\" value=\"" . $firstname . "\" />" .
 "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"lastname\" value=\"" . $lastname . "\" />" .
 "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"delete_button\" class=\"button\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Delete " . $firstname . " " . $lastname . "\" />" .
"</form>" .
"<br>";
}
```

Comment: Could you post the find_all_clients() function.

Comment: I don't see what your problem would be.  Have you tried passing `$id`, `$firstname`, `lastname` as parameters to your function?

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time to help me. This is the first time I've posted a question, though this site has already helped me countless times. 

I found that if I gave the variables a global scope in my table AND my form, the form worked; however, I have no idea why.

Comment: PS - @ bountyh function find_all_clients() {
 global $dbc;
 
 $query  = "SELECT * ";
 $query .= "FROM client_list ";
 $query .= "ORDER BY lastname ASC";
 $client_set = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
 confirm_query($client_set);
 return $client_set;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem.  I tried replicating your situation and it worked for me - calling a function from within a mysqli while loop.

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('HOST', 'USER', 'PASS', 'DATABASE');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM cds';

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $firstname = $row['titel'];
form_delete_client();
}

function form_delete_client() { 
    global $firstname;
    echo "<BR>".$firstname;
}
```

This outputs:

```
<BR>Beauty<BR>Goodbye Country (Hello Nightclub)<BR>Glee
```

Functions should work fine from within a loop.  I'm not certain why, in your case, that the data is not being fed through.  I suppose it could have something to do with you calling a `global $firstname` and the `global` is being set once and then not overwritten.  But that's just a guess.  What I would recommend doing instead is the following:

```
form_delete_client($id, $firstname, $lastname);
```

Then, your function would look like this:

```
function form_delete_client($id, $firstname, $lastname) { 
    echo $firstname;
    echo "<form id=....";
}
```

You don't need to globalize anything then.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. This is the first time I've posted a question, though this site has already helped me countless times. 

I found that if I gave the variables a global scope in my table AND my form, the form worked; however, I have no idea why.